# HTTPS and REST API with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rest, ssl, https, apache2

Firstly I implemented a rewrite rule for my REST API on an apache2 server with the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

It worked fine. If I entered e.g. `http://mypage.de/REST/SomeRule/12` my `index.php` in the folder `REST/` received the information `SomeRule/12`.

Now I enabled `SSL` on my server and I wanted to force the API to use `https` so I added the following code to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [L]
```

Now I receive a page not found error. Can you see the error in the `.htaccess` file, or must it be somewhere else? I am not that familiar with these files. To create my API I used [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html).

Comment: Can you access the APIs directly using `https://domain.com/REST/SomeRule/12` URL?

Comment: No tried this also. So Maybe it does not work with my api. Like I said, I followed the tutorial linked in my question.

Comment: If you get 404 using `https://domain.com/REST/SomeRule/12` also then you may not have setup SSL site correctly. Provide `VirtualHost` config for https site

Comment: So for `https://domain.com/REST/SomeRule/12` it says: `The requested URL /REST/SomeRule/12 was not found on this server.` It seems, that the linking to the index.php does not work.

Comment: Yes you may be using different directory as DocumentRoot in https site

Comment: You mean in my `apache2.conf` file?

Comment: yes right it should be there

Comment: Ok. So if found that in my `sites-enabled/default-ssl` file `AllowOverride None` was set. It works now, but I still have the problem that if I type in the URL as http, it is not converted to https. Do you know where I have to place this second rewrite?

Comment: Instead of `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$` try this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Comment: Why? It works that way (see answer below). Or is there some other reason?

Comment: ok if it works for you then leave it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) I found the solution.

When I updated my server to run with `https` my folder `sites-enabled` included a new file `sites-enabled/default-ssl`. In this file I had to set

```
AllowOverride All
```

like I already did for the on using `http`. I addition the correct solution for the `.htaccess` file was the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 

    #use https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
    RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]

    #used for api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I was not able to use

```
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]
```

because the `$1` then was somehow overwritten for the next Rule.